# Sample for the augmented image at the Google augmented-images page

Tags: arcore, android-augmented-reality

Is there a sample for the augmented image at the Google augmented-images page (//developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-images/)?

Answer (score 1):

OK. Found a reference to the code in Google Developers Blog entry "Creating AR Experiences for I/O: Our Process" (https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/creating-ar-experiences-for-io-our.html). The code is at https://github.com/googlesamples/arcore-illusive-images.
Thanks to those who tried to help me.